# Acquiring 2 implicits for scalacheck function

Tags: scala, generics, implicit, scalacheck

I am using scalacheck and am in the middle of a generic-programming soup right now. The official guide shows this example:

```
def matrix[T](g: Gen[T]): Gen[Seq[Seq[T]]] = Gen.sized { size =>
  val side = scala.math.sqrt(size).asInstanceOf[Int]
  Gen.listOfN(side, Gen.listOfN(side, g))
}
```

Meanwhile, for my test I require a matrix of type Array[Array[T]]. I tried with the following function:

```
def matrix[T](g: Gen[T]): Gen[Array[Array[T]]] = Gen.sized { size =>
  val side = scala.math.sqrt(size).asInstanceOf[Int]
  val g1 = Gen.containerOfN[Array, T](side, g)
  Gen.containerOfN[Array, Array[T]](side, g1)
}
```

Here, I run into trouble. The compiler says:

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - not enough arguments for method containerOfN: (implicit b: org.scalacheck.util.Buildable[T,Array])org.scalacheck.Gen[Array[T]].
>   Unspecified value parameter    b.
>     - could not find implicit value for parameter b: org.scalacheck.util.Buildable[T,Array]
>     - could not find implicit value for parameter b: org.scalacheck.util.Buildable[T,Array]
>     - not enough arguments for method containerOfN: (implicit b: org.scalacheck.util.Buildable[T,Array])org.scalacheck.Gen[Array[T]].
>   Unspecified value parameter    b.

I understand that stuff like this is usually remedied by adding implicit parameters to the function, however, i havent made this work yet.

I usually encounter this error when building generic arrays, as an example:

```
  def build[T](n:Int)(implicit m:ClassManifest[T]) = Array.ofDim[T](n)
```

but, I am afraid I don't fully understand what is happening or why this is needed.

Can someone explain **how to make the correct matrix-function** along with an **example of usage** in scalacheck? A thorough explanation of the details about building sequences with implicit class manifests would be very welcome!

**edit**

```
  import org.scalacheck.util.Buildable._
  def matrix[T](g: Gen[T])(implicit b: Buildable[T, Array]): Gen[Array[Array[T]]] = Gen.sized { size =>

    val side = scala.math.sqrt(size).asInstanceOf[Int]
    val g1 = Gen.containerOfN[Array, T](side, g)
    Gen.containerOfN[Array, Array[T]](side, g1)
  }
```

Still doesn't work. Need implicit for Buildable[Array[T],Array]... Don't know how to get this because I can only add 1 implicit argument :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. The important part of the error is `could not find implicit value for parameter b: org.scalacheck.util.Buildable[T,Array]`

Looking at the method definition of `containerOfN`

```
  def containerOfN[C[_],T](n: Int, g: Gen[T])(implicit b: Buildable[T,C]): Gen[C[T]] = ...
```

So, there's your missing argument. You need an implicit argument of type `Buildable[T,Array]`. Following through to where `Buildable` is defined in the scalacheck sources, I found that there was an object (`org.scalacheck.util.Buildable`) that provides implicits that provide `Buildable`s for the common collection types which includes `Array`. So all you need to bring that into scope. You can do this with:

```
  import org.scalacheck.util.Buildable._
  def matrix[T](g: Gen[T]): Gen[Array[Array[T]]] = Gen.sized { size =>
    val bT = implicitly[Buildable[T, Array]]
    val bArrayT = implicitly[Buildable[Array[T], Array]]

    val side = scala.math.sqrt(size).asInstanceOf[Int]
    val g1 = Gen.containerOfN[Array, T](side, g)
    Gen.containerOfN[Array, Array[T]](side, g1)
  }
```

Or

```
  import org.scalacheck.util.Buildable._
  def matrix[T](g: Gen[T])(implicit bT: Buildable[T, Array], bArrayT: Buildable[Array[T], Array]): Gen[Array[Array[T]]] = Gen.sized { size =>
    ...
  }
```

The particular implicit you need in `org.scalacheck.util.Buildable` is:

```
implicit def buildableArray[T](implicit cm: ClassManifest[T]) = 
  new Buildable[T,Array] {
    def builder = mutable.ArrayBuilder.make[T]
  }
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work. I tried importing it into the object and into the function, nothing seems to work :/ Can you give a working example?

Comment: Hmm. Looks like you need to specify the type of the Buildable that you want to implicitly import. You can do it with the `implicitly` function. Or as you tried to do with implicit parameters to the matrix function. I've edited the answer to correct it. I'm sure there's a better way to do this though.